# Which is the proper way; RBIs or RsBI?

Tags: pronunciation

Lately I have been listening to a local morning show, the sports analyst for this show, when referring to "Runs Batted In", always says (Rs - B - I) instead of (R - B - Is). I shudder every time I hear this because it just doesn't sound correct. What is the proper way to say this and why?

Comment: It is definitely RBIs. /'arbiyayz/

Comment: That sports analyst really ought to get out of baseball and into auto racing. Then he could talk about MsPH and engine RsPM.

Comment: Not a duplicate! The flagged duplicate question is about pluralising an acronym (/initialisation) which is singular. This question is about an acronym (/initialisation) which has a plural within it (i.e. not the last word in its expanded form). Definitely worthy of a separate question in my opinion. (If only I could vote to reopen!)

Answer (score 2):

I regard the acronym as a condensed version of the original. As such it has the status of a new noun and should be pluralised as such: RBIs.

Comment: But if the R stands for "runs", then surely RBI is already a plural noun?

Comment: I think it neater and easier to take the view that the basic concept is of a singular run batted in, or RBI. The plural is then RBIs.